# ADFS v2.0 : How to federate with Windows Live, OpenID and Facebook

Tags: adfs, adfs2.0

We have ADFS 2.0 running and have federated with various STS.

Is it possible to federate with Windows Live, OpenID and Facebook?

Some of our users already have these types of credentials and it would be a bonus to be able to use them.

If so, what URL would be used for the federation metadata address in the "Add Claims Provider Trust" wizard?

Any other gotchas?

Comment: [MVC 4 has this built in.](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ADFS doesn't natively support the protocols of those IP-STSs (with the possible exception of Windows Live). You'll need to put an FP-STS that understands those protocols (e.g., [PingFederate](http://www.pingidentity.com/our-solutions/pingfederate.cfm)) between ADFS and them.

Comment: In fact, you can do this with Azure, AppfabricLabs and ACS. See an example with Windows Live, Google and Yahoo here: http://acs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ASP.NET%20Simple%20Forms&referringTitle=Samples

Answer (score 3):

We have been investigating this question a lot.

It seems that the best setup is to use ACS in combination with AD FS 2.0 as [described in this article](http://blogs.objectsharp.com/cs/blogs/steve/archive/2011/04/26/creating-a-claims-provider-trust-in-adfs-2.aspx).

This setup also enables claims transformation, for example, if you want to add the corporate customer number as a claim.

We have not yet seen any examples where you can connect AD FS 2.0 directly to Facebook however.

Comment: Yes - this is the way we have gone. BTW, I don't think it would be that difficult to write your own STS that implements OAuth and Facebook Connect. The difficulty is how to validate that your STS is in fact secure.

Comment: Agreed! I want (of principle) to avoid writing my own security code, as we do not have the resources to do extensive security testing. But I think at one point we will have to. We have a CRM system where we can store usernames+passwords and use an STS to expose those.

Answer (score 0):

Yes . there are no direct way to get the claims from ADFS , need to configure the ACS and need to set the ACS as ID providers to ADFS.
But the token validation for ACS is 24 hours at max , so you need to be happy with short-lived token for Social Id providers.